# Are champion-specific rune pages needed in order to be competitive?

Tags: league-of-legends

ATM I always have a runepage for general ADC's, Junglers etc. but not for specific champions, does it make a big difference if you play with general runes or runes for every specific champion? I mean do you have big disadvantages that matter, or should I only take the afford for ranked games?

Would be great if an experienced player could give some feedback on this :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you're trying out a very unique and special build, rune pages for a specific role are often very similar. For example, most ADC's want attack damage or armor penetration, armor, magic resistance (per level) and either more attack damage, more armor penetration, or attack speed. Which of the choices you pick depends more on your preferences and play style, as they are all viable for most ADC's. Ideally, you'd want a specialised rune page for each group of champions, but if you're short on IP or rune pages, this makes too little of a difference to matter.

If you're mainly playing a single role and have several champions available for it, creating several rune pages for that role and just one generic page for each other role you can play is your best bet. That way, you can diversify within your role, but keep the flexibility to play any role. This again depends on the number of rune pages and runes you have in the first place. The flexibility is much more important than the diversity within one role. It's better to be able to play whatever role your team needs well than to play only one role perfectly.

But you really don't need a page per champion. Actually, if you start making them, you will notice that the differences are sometimes simply not there and sometimes negligible. You might also notice that different people and guides use different rune pages for the same reasons. That also shows it's more or less irrelevant which approach you take and you can very well use only one rune page for several or all champions fulfilling a specific role.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, rune pages can be shared by multiple champions.  There are times though where rune pages can be extremely effective when they are made for a specific champion.

Standard AD Page: AD Marks, Armor Seals, MR Glyphs, AD Quints/Lifesteal

Ezreal AD Page: AD Marks, Armor Seals, Mixing MR Glyphs with Mana Regen, AD Quints

Standard AD Jungler: AD Marks, Armor Seals, Scaling MR Glyphs, AD Quints

Nocturne Jungler: AS Marks, Armor Seals, Scaling MR, AS quints

Standard AP Tank Top: Hybrid Marks, Armor Seals, MR Glyphs, AD/AP Quints

Mundo Top: Hybrid Marks, Armor Seals, MR Glyphs, HP/5 Quints

Ryze Top: Hybrid Marks, Armor Seals, Mana Glyphs, Mana Quints

Notice that a the standard pages, multiple champions can use.  Some champions work very well with specific rune pages though which gives them a nice advantage in lane.

Ezreal tends to be very poke heavy and can run out of mana fairly quickly if you poke hard.  Adding some Mana regen in place of some MR can win you the lane by letting your extra poke whittle down the enemy forcing them to either play defensive or potentially die.

Many junglers like Pantheon or VI build straight AD for damage from abilities.  Some junglers synergize very well with the new Feral Flare or do more damage overall the faster they attack and so instead of damage building lots of attack speed greatly increases their damage output.

Many top laners will have pretty similar builds.  Some tanky ones like Malphite or Shen might run those standard pages I show up top.  Other tanks like Mundo don't benefit from the same.  Mundo tends to farm with his cleaver which constantly drains his HP.  He needs the extra health regen quints to safely farm from afar to keep his HP up.  Ryze gets a huge bonus from having extra mana to damage.  Level 1, if you have all mana Glphys/Quints can get his level 1 spell damage to 109.  This is pretty significant.

Basically, you don't **NEED** to have additional rune pages.  You can get away with having 2-5 but if you are vs a similarly skilled player, your better runes could give you the edge to win the match and potentially snowball your lane.  Currently, I run 19 rune pages for a variety of champions.

Comment: I just wanna add a tiny little detail about your Jungler page: AS runes help more than AD runes since you benefit more from the on hit effect of Machete. Even then, I'd advice you to switch to MS quints as they can affect both jungling speed AND ganking efficiency.

Comment: Some junglers you want the AS and some junglers you want the AD.  It really does depend on the jungler.  Lately, I haven't been noticing ppl running as many MS quints as they used to also.

Comment: Well, if you name some junglers who benefit from AD more than AS, I could run some "tests" < u <

Comment: Pantheon and Kha'Zix are the first 2 that come to mind.

Comment: Pantheon would increase his sustain vs jungle mobs with increased attack speed to proc his shield. Not sure about zix though. Would you start with Q or W? W would give more sustain, and scales with AP anyway, so AS runes. Q would scale with AD, but then you wouldn't need the machete to begin with and could run with cloth+pots, though that would just cripple his jungle speed by so much that you're better off playing a different assassin.

Comment: With Pantheon and Kha'Zix, you aren't concerned about the sustain from attack speed over damage.  The damage is to make your ganks more dangerous.  Pantheon and Kha'Zix though are picked for their early gank power.  Not their clear speeds/sustain.  They fall off late game and so need to win the game early.  I don't know the exact abilities I'd start with Kha but I know for a fact it is generally accepted as better to start AD over AS.

Answer (score 1):

Having a perfect, specialized set of runes can sometimes give you a tiny advantage in a lane/game.  However, the lane/game is overwhelmingly determined by your skill with the individual champion first, and champion matchups second.  Runes are a tertiary factor at best, and it requires a pretty high skill level for this to really be a relevant issue.

Therefore, you can get by for a long time with generic runes on the vast majority of champions.  If you have a lot of IP sitting around, you can spend some time thinking about idealized runes and whatnot, but if you don't have the IP, I wouldn't spend much time worrying about it.  Even in, say, platinum level play, you don't need *that* many rune pages.

You can get away with 5 pages minimum (basically one for each role), but having about 7 is a slightly safer number (to cover the possibility of facing an AD mid or an AP heavy top).  From there you can build specialized pages for specific champions.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread has been answered already but still, my view on this...
Some champions can share rune pages like described above.
However, some champions require a personal rune page depending on how you play that champion.
For myself, I have a special rune page (and masterie page) for my Ezreal. I play Ezreal like noone plays him, but it works for me. I play it with AD quints, AD marks, flat health seals and CDR glyphs.
This gives me 10% CDR but then I would have no magic resistance. Therefore I replaced the nerfed armor seals with flat health.
For me, this is the perfect balance, but it's a pretty weak start build.

It all depends on how you play basically. Some people like to have AD marks on mages mid to be able to last hit better and to have a bit more harass early game in laning phase, but not everyone likes that.

So basically: you should stick with a few champions and master them so you know whether to use specific rune pages or not :).